SQL server randomly disconnects the client
I'm developing a service that connects to ms sql server 2017 (running on windows server 2016) and does some work. It worked fine for years and now it started disconnect randomly. the error is

SQLSTATE[08S01]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]TCP Provider: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

The event viewer shows nothing. There are some errors on test databases (I'm not the admin):

The log shipping primary database SRV\DATA.testdb1 has backup threshold of 60 minutes and has not performed a backup log operation for 696777 minutes. Check agent log and logshipping monitor information.

I don't think they have anything to do with the problem. It's not even on a production database - it's an old copy made for testing.
More info:
I'm connecting with PHP. The php and the extension/driver was outdated - 7.4. I updated it to 8.2 and fetched latest driver from microsoft.
The server is open to the internet. It's possible that lots of hack attempts can result too many connections.
I made a simple test that connects and selects a row from a table. Sometimes it fails right away, sometimes it'll work for days before failing.
How do I debug that? Can I make SQL server to log the cause of the disconnect?
Update
Here are some errors from the log These two are about 3 minutes away from the error email. They are also from a source that doesn't report no-backup messages:
Error: 59999, severity 16, state 1 was raised, but no message with that error number was found in sys.messages. If error is larger than 50000, make sure the user-defined message is added using sp_addmessage.
Error: 18054, Severity: 16, State: 1.

Also these come together with the "no backup" messages, but they are about temporary test databases:
Error: 14420, Severity: 16, State: 1.
Error: 3041, Severity: 16, State: 1.


"nd has not performed a backup log operation for 696777 minutes" Why have you not performed a log back up in in almost 17 months?!

"The server is open to the internet. It's possible that lots of hack attempts can result too many connections." Surely you have a firewall in place and a white list of IPs, no?

that's a copy of a database that's made for something. it's not an important database

@ThomA. I'm not sure they have ip filter. There are lots of clients all over the country. Some of them don't have fixed ips. I'll recommend them to switch to VPN

Have you checked the SQL Server Error Log https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/view-the-sql-server-error-log-sql-server-management-studio?view=sql-server-ver16 Also "The server is open to the internet" oh dear dear dear....

@Charlieface I updated the question with what I found in the log

Hmmm those errors (the first two) are undocumented https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/database-engine-events-and-errors?view=sql-server-ver16 Which exact build number are you on? select @@version Have you run DBCC CHECKDB on all databases, including master, recently?
